# Windows only writes to file after process is stopped

Tags: python, windows, io-redirection

I wrote a really simple script to test out the redirection of windows machine `stdout`. The program is as such

```
# hw.py
def main():
    print('Hello World')
    import time
    time.sleep(1000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I ran this script using the following command.

```
python3 hw.py > hw.log
```

By observing in real time `hw.log` using either `tail -f` on git bash or opening an `emacs` buffer, I noticed that `'Hello World'` is only printed to `hw.log` when the process ends, or it is cancelled prematurely.

---

This means that I cannot have a live view of a program output while writing it to a file.
Worst still, if my program consists of infinite child processes, any output from the program will not be written to the file

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To force the Python stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered you can pass the [`-u`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) argument.

```
python3 -u hw.py > hw.log
```

Setting the environment variable [`PYTHONBUFFERRED=1`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED) will have the same effect

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. Out of curiosity, how come I've never faced this issue on linux platforms?

Comment: No worries. I'm not entirely certain why so I wouldn't like to speculate!

Comment: @Tian, I experience the same buffering issue in Linux with both Python 2.x and 3.x. I can't say why you haven't experienced it.

Comment: @Tian, Windows filesystems do have some oddities about when the directory entry and file stat info are updated. FAT32 will immediately update the directory entry and direct stat info for the file size, but it doesn't update the last-write time until the file is either closed or flushed via `FlushFileBuffers`, i.e. Python `os.fsync(f.fileno())`. NTFS won't update either the size or the last-write time in the directory entry until it's either accessed (e.g. via `os.stat`) or flushed with `FlushFileBuffers`, but neither case will update directory entries for the file's other hardlinks, if any.

Comment: Note that a Python file's `flush` method is just for its own buffer, not OS caching. So to completely flush a file, use `f.flush()` and `os.fsync(f.fileno())`.